# Как сделать из одного компьютера два

Tags: windows-7, железо

Имеем ноутбук, где соответственно есть и мышь и монитор и клава + есть второй монитор, вторая мышь и вторая клавиатура. Дисплей ноутбука не нравится, из-за этого подключил к ноутбуку вторую клавиатуру, мышь  и монитор (завалялся от старого). Ноутбук на Win7 второй монитор нашёл, перетащил картинку на него, и сижу радуюсь :) Появилась идея. Может как нибудь можно сделать два компьютера из одного. Т.е в устройствах же висит две клавы, две мыши и два монитора. Может быть как нибудь гостевую ОС запустить и пусть она ловит события от первой клавы а основная ОС от второй, также с мышью. Ибо 8-летний братишка надоел со своими играми :)

Comment: [вариант 1](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/238/238r.shtml) [вариант 2](http://www.ibik-soft.com/)